# How to run tflite model not on image classification swift

Tags: swift, xcode, tensorflow, audio, tensorflow-lite

I have seen several tutorials on how to run a tflite model for image classification, but don’t know how to do it for any other application... For example, I have a model that takes in audio data in the form of a (16000, 1) array. How can I pass this array into the tflite model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tflite works with byte buffers.

You have to convert all inputs to the byte buffers, e.g.

```
let len = 16000
var audio = [Float](repeating: Float(1.0), count: len)
let audioBuffer = Data(bytes: &audio, count: audio.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)
try interpreter.copy(audioBuffer, toInputAt: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TensorFlow Lite` provides all the tools we need to convert and run `TensorFlow models` on mobile, embedded, and IoT devices.

To use a `model` with `TensorFlow Lite`, we must convert a full `TensorFlow model` into the `TensorFlow Lite` format.  We cannot create or train a model using `TensorFlow Lite`. So we must start with a regular `TensorFlow model`, and then [convert the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started#2_convert_the_model_format).

See full list of pre-trained models which are ready to use in applications : [in Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models).

If we have designed and trained our own TensorFlow model, or we have trained a model obtained from another source, we must convert it to the TensorFlow Lite format.

**Reference :**  [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to load the model, however, I do not know how to use the model that I loaded. How do I pass in an array of floats?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the model which you are using? Have you converted your model to TensorFlow Lite format ?

Comment: yes it is a model which takes in audio data as a float (defined in the original question) and predicts based on that.

Comment: have you converted that model to TensorFlow Lite format ?